# compare each rows and assign number and total it in R

Tags: r, matrix, compare, rows

I am very new with R and i used to refer a lot here in stackoverflow.
I would like to compare each row with rest of the rows to calculate the modified similarity matrix.

```
mat <- matrix("", 10, 12)
mat[c(1, 4, 6),] <- sample(c("AA", "AB", "BB"), 18, TRUE)
mat[c(2, 3, 10),] <- sample(c("AA", "BB", "AB"), 18, TRUE)
mat[c(5, 8),] <- sample(c("BB", "AB", "BB"), 12, TRUE)
mat[c(7, 9),] <- sample(c("AA", "AA", "BB"), 12, TRUE)
mat[3,4] = 'NA'
mat[2,5] = 'NA'
```

this provides:

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12]
 [1,] "AA" "AA" "AB" "AA" "AA" "AA" "AA" "AA" "AB" "AA"  "AA"  "AA" 
 [2,] "AB" "AA" "BB" "BB" "NA" "AB" "AB" "AA" "BB" "BB"  "BB"  "AB" 
 [3,] "BB" "AA" "AB" "NA" "AA" "AA" "BB" "AA" "AB" "AA"  "AA"  "AA" 
 [4,] "AA" "AA" "BB" "AB" "AA" "AB" "AA" "AA" "BB" "AB"  "AA"  "AB" 
 [5,] "AB" "AB" "BB" "BB" "AB" "AB" "AB" "AB" "BB" "BB"  "AB"  "AB" 
 [6,] "AA" "AA" "AB" "AA" "AB" "AA" "AA" "AA" "AB" "AA"  "AB"  "AA" 
 [7,] "BB" "AA" "AA" "BB" "AA" "AA" "BB" "AA" "AA" "BB"  "AA"  "AA" 
 [8,] "AB" "BB" "BB" "BB" "AB" "BB" "AB" "BB" "BB" "BB"  "AB"  "BB" 
 [9,] "AA" "AA" "BB" "BB" "AA" "AA" "AA" "AA" "BB" "BB"  "AA"  "AA" 
[10,] "BB" "AB" "AA" "BB" "BB" "BB" "BB" "AB" "AA" "BB"  "BB"  "BB"
```

I would like to compare each row with rest of the rows to calculate modified similarity matrix.

Step 1:
Assign values by comparing two rows

```
AA Vs AA = 1;
AA Vs AB = 0.5;
AA Vs NA = 0.0;
NA Vs NA = 0.0;
AB Vs AA = 0.5;
AA Vs BB = 0.0;
AB Vs AB = 0.5
```

Step 2:
Total the scores (example row 1 versus row 2 = 7.0)

Step 3: 
Count the total numbers excluding the instances where there is one or two 'NA'  (example row 1 versus row 2 = 11.0),

Step 4:
Divide the total scores by the count(example row 1 versus row2 7/11=0.636363)

Step 5:
Do it for each rows and get the result in matrix populated in both diagonals (Example 10 X 10)

Thanks in Advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will change your matrix definition a bit to make `"NA"` characters into actual missing values (`NA`) which have a special meaning in R that is close to the behavior you want.

```
mat <- matrix("", 10, 12)
mat[c(1, 4, 6),] <- sample(c("AA", "AB", "BB"), 18, TRUE)
mat[c(2, 3, 10),] <- sample(c("AA", "BB", "AB"), 18, TRUE)
mat[c(5, 8),] <- sample(c("BB", "AB", "BB"), 12, TRUE)
mat[c(7, 9),] <- sample(c("AA", "AA", "BB"), 12, TRUE)
mat[3,4] <- NA
mat[2,5] <- NA
```

You also have not provided with the values of all possible matches, so I am going to make some assumptions. These values can be changed without breaking the code.

For step 1, I am going to make a named vector that can be indexed using the pair names bunched together. So AA vs BA becomes `'AABA'`.

```
pair <- c('AAAA', 'AAAB', 'AABB', 'ABAB', 'ABBB', 'BBBB')
value <- c(1, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 0.5, 1)
# add reverse pairing (I am assuming symmetry)
pair <- c(pair, paste0(substr(pair, 3, 4), substr(pair, 1, 2)))
value <- c(value, value)
names(value) <- pair
```

Check how the vector `value` looks at this point to make sure it's what you want. Next we define a function that uses this globally defined vector and returns what you want at the end of step 4. You may want to include the vector definition in the function body, but I feel that would not be efficient.

```
compare <- function(row1, row2){
  # get total value of match from 2 vectors
  # get vector of complete cases (not having any NAs)
  good.cases <- complete.cases(cbind(row1, row2))
  na.cases <- length(row1) - good.cases
  total.value <- sum(value[paste0(row1, row2)], na.rm=TRUE) + 0.5*na.cases
  total.value/good.cases
}
```

At this point I get `total.value` of 6.5 from comparing the first 2 rows, but that is probably due to a wrong assumption in `value`.

For step 5, we use a double loop:

```
# start empty matrix with match values
n <- nrow(mat)
matches <- matrix(rep(NA, n*n), nrow=n)
for (i in 1:n){
  for (j in i:n){  ## if symmetric, only half matrix is enough
    matches[i, j] <- compare(mat[i, ], mat[j, ])
  }
}
```

I hope that helps.

**Edit:** Changed `compare()` to assign a value to NA cases after request in the comments.

Comment: Thanks ilir ! But I get error, when i wanted to use the function compare.   mat1 <- compare(mat) got me "Error in paste0(row1, row2) : argument "row2" is missing, with no default". Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: Yes, `compare` takes two rows at a time. It's the double loop at the end that populates a matrix (called `matches` here). That's the result you want.

Comment: ilir  sorry again !...the matrix is the one I am looking for...however i am expecting  1.0 for diagonals of the same row. Example when we take row 1 vs row1, row2 vs row 2…and so on, we expect 1.0.

Comment: You would not get that according to your matching scores above. The average for a row full of `"AB"` would be 0.5, for example. Make sure the scores for each match are assigned correctly (vector `value`), I just went by your examples and by assumption.

Comment: got it..!...i simply replace the self comparisons into 1.0. Thanks again !

Comment: ilir...if i want to give weight of 0.5 for 'ABNA', 'BANA', NABA and 'NAAB' (NA is a missing data) and include them in the total count, what should be the best way ?..

Comment: Then 'NA' will have to be a value like all others (cannot be missing in the R sense) because we need to count it. Add the combos with 'NA' to the `pair` vector and the corresponding values to the `value` vector and you are good.

Comment: ilir....That's the same I was also thinking, but for counting I don't want to include AANA, NAAA, BBNA, NABB and NANA. Sorry for long conversation !!..i highly appreciate your prompt reply

Comment: Sorry, I had not read the question correctly. I changed the answer to account for that.

Comment: Thanks ilir. Could you help me to get answer for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24025604/how-to-create-a-matrix-in-r-using-the-rows-and-coloum-data